# How to use QVariant::fromValue with QString?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qvariant

I have the following code:

```
QString* data = new QString("data to QML");
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("consoleText"), QVariant::fromValue(data));
```

and this one does not work, the error message in QTCreator is the following:

> ...\qglobal.h:693: error: static assertion failed: Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known
>   to Qt's meta-object system
>        #define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)

I do no think that I should use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` for `QString` because if I do something like this:

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("consoleText"), QVariant::fromValue(QString("data to QML")));
```

it works fine.

I am interested in that how can I use the `QVariant::fromValue()` with a pre-declared QString.

Comment: Don't allocate `QString` on the heap, it is entirely pointless.

Comment: I was just testing how to connect QML with c++ side, did not pay attention to other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QVariant::fromValue()` expects a `QString`, not a pointer to a `QString`.

Additionally, allocating a `QString` object on the heap doesn't make much sense. Under the hood, `QString` uses copy-on-write (COW) as an optimization; the actual data stored in the `QString` will always be on the heap anyway.

Comment: I am just testing this is not a valid code, the `QString` will be filled by a `QSerialPort`.

Comment: Aaaah that mask at on your cat is awesome. :D (Ok, mark this as "too chatty")

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a pointer to a `QString`, not a `QString` itself. To use the `QVariant::fromValue()` method, you must dereference the pointer:

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("consoleText"), QVariant::fromValue(*data));
                                                                                            ^
```

This is because a `QString *` is not a registered meta-type (by default).